# Exchanging multiple pairs of characters in a Haskell string

Tags: string, haskell, replace

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that takes a string of pairs of letters, and exchanges the letters of the pair in a string of all letters, but what I've come up with feels awkward and unidiomatic.

I have

```
swap a b = map (\x-> if x == a then b else if x == b then a else x)
sub n = foldr (.) id (zipWith swap (head <$> splitOn "." n) (last <$> splitOn "." n)) ['A'..'Z']
```

which works well enough giving

```
> sub "RB.XD.EU.ZM.IJ"
"ARCXUFGHJIKLZNOPQBSTEVWDYM"
```

and

```
> sub "YC.LU.EB.TZ.RB.XD.IJ"
"ARYXBFGHJIKUMNOPQESZLVWDCT"
```

but I'm new to Haskell and feel like my approach — especially my `swap` helper function (which I only use here) — is more elaborate than it needs to be.

Is there a better, more idiomatic, approach to this problem; especially one that takes advantage of a language feature, builtin, or library function that I've missed?

Comment: Note you can write `"ABCDE..."` as `['A'..'Z']` due to `Char` being an instance of `Enum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a left fold over the substitution list makes the code shorter:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

sub = foldl' swap ['A'..'Z'] . splitOn "." . reverse
  where
    swap az [a,b] = map (\x -> if x == a then b else if x == b then a else x) az
```

Drop the reverse if you don't care whether `EB` or `RB` is swapped first.

If you'd want to replace instead of a swap:

```
import Data.List
import Data.List.Split

replace needle replacement haystack =
    intercalate replacement (splitOn needle haystack)

rep = foldl' replace' ['A'..'Z'] . splitOn "."
    where
        replace' az [a,b] = replace [a] [b] az
```

Comment: Exactly. And this also much more elegantly highlights the logic (namely the role of pairs).

Answer (score 2):

I'd break the problem down a bit more.  It's important to remember that shorter code is not necessarily the best code.  Your implementation works, but it's too compact for me to quickly understand.  I'd recommend something more like

```
import Data.Maybe (mapMaybe)

swap = undefined -- Your current implementation is fine,
                 -- although you could rewrite it using
                 -- a local function instead of a lambda

-- |Parses the swap specification string into a list of
-- of characters to swap as tuples
parseSwap :: String -> [(Char, Char)]
parseSwap = mapMaybe toTuple . splitOn "."
    where
        toTuple (first:second:_) = Just (first, second)
        toTuple _ = Nothing

-- |Takes a list of characters to swap and applies it
-- to a target string
sub :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String
sub charsToSwap = foldr (.) id (map (uncurry swap) charsToSwap)
```

The equivalent to your `sub` function would be

```
sub swapSpec = foldr (.) id (map (uncurry swap) $ parseSwap swapSpec)
```

But the former is probably easier to understand for most haskellers.  You could also do more transformations more easily to your swap specification as a list of tuples making it more powerful overall.  You essentially decouple the representation of the swap specification and the actual swapping.  Even for small programs like this it's important to maintain loose coupling so that you develop a habit for when you write larger programs!

This implementation also avoids recalculating `splitOn` for the swap specification string.

<strike>(I wasn't able to execute this code because I'm on a computer without Haskell installed, if anyone notices any bugs please edit to fix.)</strike> Tried it out in FPComplete, output matches @raxacoricofallapatorius'.

Comment: This is breaking things up a bit too much (see my comment on [duplode's question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32317588/656912)).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius In almost every context, you'll find that the generally accepted wisdom is to first parse your input into a useful data structure, then utilize it in another step.  This is to separate the code that does the parsing from the code that does the processing, since it's usually easier to worry about each of those concerns separately.  Also, note the last line of code I gave, showing how to go from the `.` delimited string directly to having performed the swap.  It was built from the smaller tool of `parseSwap` and the definition of `sub :: [(Char, Char)] -> String String`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius You can still only export or use the version that takes a swap specification rather than a `[(Char, Char)]` for user convenience, but internally you can use whatever representation you want.  This gives _you_ flexibility and power to implement the internals of your program.  As another example, you rarely see the code for parsing JSON or XML interleaved with using the values obtained from a JSON or XML document, there's always a parsing step before any processing.

Answer (score 1):

Some things I noticed from reading your code (I haven't tried to rewrite it). My first suggestion involves separation of concerns:

> I'm trying to write a Haskell function that takes a string of pairs of letters, and exchanges the letters of the pair in a string of all letters

That means the a more natural type for your function would be:

```
sub :: [(Char, Char)] -> String -> String
```

Or, using [`Data.Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html) for more efficient lookups:

```
sub :: Map Char Char -> String -> String
```

Which is a lot more precise than taking a string with dot-separated pairs. You can then generate the associations between `Char`s in a separate step:

```
parseCharPairs :: String -> Map Char Char
```

Ideally you should also handle invalid inputs (e.g. `AB.CDE`) and empty input strings.

> my `swap` helper function (which I only use here)

Then you probably should define it in a `where` clause. I would also avoid the name `swap`, as there is a relatively common function in `Data.Tuple` with the same name (`swapLetters` might be a nice choice).

```
sub n = foldr (.) id -- etc.
```

`foldr (.) id (fmap f xs) y` is the same thing as `foldr f y xs`. I'm almost certain this can be rewritten in a simpler way.

Comment: The context here is very much about translating a string of pairs of letters delimited by periods (that's a constraint) into a string where the substitutions have been made. Having an intermediate structure is not (in my view) helpful in this context. This is part of a (user) input step provided as a convenience.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It might not be helpful for the end user, but it certainly is for the author (i.e. you). Decomposing in smaller functions makes it easier to specify, understand and test the code. As for the end user, function composition means you can always provide an `endUserSub =  sub . parseCharPairs` that does everything in one step. If you don't think your users will need the intermediate functions, you don't even need to export them from your module.