# Haskell idiom for setting up a collection of indexed structured values

Tags: haskell, coding-style, associative-array, idioms

I have a collection of about a dozen structured things of a type I've defined (say `Component`), each of which can be identified by a "name", and am struggling to sort out an idiomatic Haskell way of instantiating and retrieving them. These things are used frequently in my application, so conceptually they are a set of global constants or a table of constants, that ideally would be initialized and saved for fast retrieval.

My current approach, which I'm uncomfortable with, just uses a function to "compute" each `Component` from its name.

```
data Component = Component {
                    someData :: !String,
                    otherData :: ![Int] 
                } deriving Show

component :: Name -> Component
component n = case n of
    -- about a dozen in the application
    "1"       -> Component "lasdkfj;alksdjfalkf" [1]
    "Q"       -> Component "nvjufhhqwe" [5,10,11]
    "other"   -> Component "ugugugu" []
    "A"       -> Component "alkkjsfkjaleifuhqiweufjc" []
    "B"       -> Component "randomletters" []
    "C"       -> Component "nothingimportant" [9,10]
    "b"       -> Component "uk" []
    "c"       -> Component "x" [4,2,7,9,0]
    ""        -> Component "ABC" []
    -- if not listed above, the Component is computed
    otherwise -> Component (someFunctionOf n) (someOtherFunctionOf n)
```

This doesn't feel right to me. For one thing, the `Component`'s name is really a part of the `Component`, but isn't included in the type. More importantly, even constant values get computed, when in fact they should just be initialized in some table.

With this in mind I've also tried

```
type Name = String

import Data.Maybe
import Data.Map

data Component = Component {
                    name :: Name,
                    someDate :: String,
                    otherData :: [Int] 
                } deriving Show

components = fromList $ (\c -> (name c, c)) <$> [
    Component "1" "lasdkfj;alksdjfalkf" [1],
    Component "Q" "nvjufhhqwe" [5,10,11],
    Component "other" "ugugugu" [],
    Component "A" "alkkjsfkjaleifuhqiweufjc" [],
    Component "B" "randomletters" [],
    Component "C" "nothingimportant" [9,10],
    Component "b" "uk" [],
    Component "c" "x" [4,2,7,9,0],
    Component "" "ABC" []
    ]

component :: Name -> Component
component n | isNothing c = Component n (someFunctionOf n) (someOtherFunctionOf n) 
            | otherwise   = fromJust c  
        where c = Data.Map.lookup n components
```

This has the advantage of clearly treating the "constant" values as constants, but feels awkward, since it introduces an intermediate value (the `Map` `components`) and duplicates the name there (in the `Component` and as the corresponding key).

Anyway, I feel like I'm going about this all wrong, and that there must be a better way to set up an indexed set of structured values, that include a bunch of constants as well as computed ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Map`-based solution looks fine to me. Two minor adjustments: firstly, you should do a qualified import of `Data.Map`, to avoid name clashes:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Map (Map)
```

The second `import` is there just for extra convenience. With it, you don't need to write `M.Map` in the type signatures.

Secondly, `isNothing` and `isJust` are not very idiomatic. It is clearer to use `maybe`, `fromMaybe` or to simply pattern match on the `Maybe` value. As a bonus, if you do so you don't need to use `fromJust` (which is avoided whenever possible because it is partial).

```
component :: Name -> Component
component n = fromMaybe
    (Component n (someFunctionOf n) (someOtherFunctionOf n))
    (M.lookup n components)
```

> but feels awkward, since it introduces an intermediate value (the `Map` `components`)

I know [we couldn't persuade you last time around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317206/exchanging-multiple-pairs-of-characters-in-a-haskell-string), but there really is nothing wrong with introducing intermediate values. Doing so can make code easier to understand, by making it clearer what each of the parts are doing, and to reuse. If you won't need the `components` map anywhere else (as is likely the case) and don't want to make a top level definition for it, just put it in a `where` clause.

> and duplicates the name there

That is an annoyance, though a relatively small one. If the users of your code do not have access to the `components` dictionary, they cannot introduce mistakes by changing the name under which a component is stored; only you can do so. Still, if you want to minimise the number of places at which you can introduce mistakes (which is a legitimate goal in itself), you can change the type of `components` to...

```
components :: Map Name ComponentData
```

... in which `ComponentData` is your original, name-less, definition of `Component`. The `component` function, which is the one users will actually see, can retain its current type: just introduce something like...

```
giveNameToComponent :: Name -> ComponentData -> Component
```

... and change its definition to...

```
component :: Name -> Component
component n = fromMaybe
    (Component n (someFunctionOf n) (someOtherFunctionOf n))
    (giveNameToComponent n <$> M.lookup n components)
```

... or, equivalently but using `maybe`:

```
component :: Name -> Component
component n = maybe
    (Component n (someFunctionOf n) (someOtherFunctionOf n))
    (giveNameToComponent n)
    (M.lookup n components)
```

Comment: Excellent! Can you say a bit more about your remark about the second import (`import Data.Map (Map)`). Also I think I need `M.fromList`. Is my lambda for generating `components` ok? I do indeed "control" that, so the duplication of "name" isn't such an issue (as you correctly point out). Is there a Haskell idiom for naming such "private" or "internal" values?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius (1) The `import Data.Map (Map)` is just to make the type signatures a little less noisy. It is perfectly okay to leave it out; it only means you'll have to write `components :: M.Map Name Component`. (2) `M.fromList`, indeed. (3) The lambda is fine. There are point-free ways of writing that, such as `liftA2 (,) name id` (`liftA2` is in `Control.Applicative`) and `name &&& id` (`(&&&)` is in `Control.Arrow`), but in this case the choice is largely a matter of taste (some people will think the point-free versions are cleaner, while others will find them obfuscating).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius (4) "Is there a Haskell idiom for naming such "private" or "internal" values?" -- Not really; just name them as you would name anything else. That also means having reasonably clear names even for internal values, to make it easier for people reading your implementation. Also, it is generally okay to have shorter and less descriptive names for things that have local scope (function parameters, `where` clause definitions, etc.), as in most cases it will be possible to spot all uses of local names in a quick glance.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed responses. `&&&` is great, and I can describe what it does in words, but I'm [mystified by how its type signature matches that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32550132/656912)!