# How to make sense of the Haskell type signature for Control.Arrow's '&&&' operator

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm trying to wrap my head around how Haskell's `Control.Arrow`'s [`&&&`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) works, but fear I'm on the verge of losing my way.

Specifically, I'm confused (as a beginner) by how to makes sense of its behavior from the type signature

```
(&&&) :: a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')
```

in

```
import Control.Arrow
(negate &&& (+5)) <$> [1,2,3]
```

or even just

```
(negate &&& (+5)) 5
```

for example, the first argument is "missing" `b` and `c`, while the second is missing just `c'`, and the result looks to me like `(c, c')`, not `a b (c, c')`.

Can someone walk me through how `&&&` works, in the context of its type?

Comment: The type `A -> B` can also be written `(->) A B`. For example, `negate :: (->) Integer Integer`.

Comment: @melpomene: I can get that far, but what I'n stumbling over is how it can be the same as `\c -> (negate c, (+5) c)`. For one thing, the result is `(c, c')`. (Headache!)

Comment: The `a` in the arrow signature is the equivalent of `->`.  If we could use infix syntax in type-signatures you could write: ```(&&&) :: b `a` c -> b `a` c' -> b `a` (c, c')```.  So the first argument is a "function" from `b` to `c`, the second is a "function" from `b` to `c'` and the result is a function from `b` to `(c, c')`.

Comment: Just try `:type (negate &&& (+5))`

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, clearly. But how did I get there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I always think of `&&&` as a split and apply operation. You've got an Arrow value, and you're going to apply two functions (sorry, arrows, but it works with functions and makes explanations easier) to it, and keep both results, thus splitting the stream.

Dead simple example:

```
λ> (succ &&& pred) 42
(43,41)
```

Walking the type there, we've got

```
succ &&& pred :: Arrow a, Enum b => a b (b,b)
```

A more complex example where it's not all b:

```
show &&& (== 42) :: Arrow a, Show b, Eq b, Num b => a b (String,Bool)
```

So in plain english: `&&&` takes two functions, and combines them into a single function that takes it input, applies both functions to it, and returns the result pair.

But it's defined on arrows, not functions.  Yet it works exactly the same: it takes two arrows, and combines them into a single arrow that takes its input, applies both arrows to it, and returns the result pair.

```
arrowOne :: Arrow a => a b c
arrowTwo :: Arrow a => a b c'
arrowOne &&& arrowTwo :: Arrow a => a b (c,c')
```

Addendum: part of what seems to confuse you is whether or not the `a` type still appears in the type signatures.  The rule of thumb here is that it works the same as for when you see the `->` in function types: it shows as long as it's not applied.

I recall reading some Arrow literature that wrote arrows as `b ~> c` (note the tilde not dash) instead of `a b c`, to make the parallel with functions more apparent.

Comment: Your addendum is correct. That's exactly what I was missing: ` (->)` is distinct from the `->` in the type signatures I'm used to, so that my `negate`, for example, isn't `a`, its `a b c`, or rather  `b -> c` (or  `b ~> c`). In other words, `negate` matches *all* of `a b c` as an `Arrow` that takes `b`s and produces `c`s ( `b ~> c`) which happens to be a function that takes `b`s and produces `c`s (`b -> c`). Right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius That's exactly it. `negate` is a function, you're using it as an argument to `&&&` which expects arrows, and it works because functions are arrows. It returns a specific arrow of the kind you handed it with: another function.

Answer (score 9):

The signature says,

```
(&&&) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')
```

and [`(->)` is an instance of `Arrow` type class.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#line-139) So, rewriting the signature specialized for `(->)` type:

```
(&&&) :: ((->) b c) -> ((->) b c') -> ((->) b (c, c'))
```

in, infix form it will look like:

```
(b -> c) -> (b -> c') -> (b -> (c, c'))
```

which simply means

```
(&&&) :: (b -> c)   -- given a function from type `b` to type `c`
      -> (b -> c')  -- and another function from type `b` to type `c'`
      -> (b -> (c, c')) -- returns a function which combines the result of
                        -- first and second function into a tuple
```

a simple replication would be:

```
(&:&) :: ((->) b c) -> ((->) b c') -> ((->) b (c, c'))
f &:& g = \x -> (f x, g x)
```

which would work the same way:

```
\> (negate &:& (+5)) <$> [1, 2, 3]
[(-1,6),(-2,7),(-3,8)]
```

Comment: What I was missing was that ` (->)` is different from the `->` in the type signatures I'm used to, so that my `negate`, for example, isn't `a`, its `a b c`. (Right?)

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius right, `negate` is `a b c`, and `(->)` is `a`, which is then consistent because negate is `b -> c` the infix form of `(->) b c`.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a bunch of great answers; I just wanted to add how to understand this thing *by only looking at the syntax*.

The rules for Haskell's type language are the same as Haskell's normal language: `f a b = (f a) b` is some type-function `f` applied to some type-argument `a` to produce another type-function `f a` which is being applied to some type-argument `b`. Then there is one operator (and some compiler flags allow you to enable others) `->` which denotes the type of functions which expect the first type as input and return the second type as output.

So the expression `(&&&) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')` means "The type of functions from `a b c` to functions from `a b c'` to `a b (c, c')` with the added constraint that `a` is a member of the Arrow typeclass.

There are lots of different sorts of arrows; this says "I take two arrows of the same sort, one from `b` to `c` and another from `b` to `c'`, and combine them together into an arrow of that same sort, from `b` to `(c, c')`."

Intuitively, we'd say that it composes the two arrows "in parallel" so that they both act on the same input, produce their different outputs, and then we "join" those outputs with our inhomogeneous-pair data structure `(,)`.

For the special case where the arrow is `(->)`, the function arrow, this is clearly `(f &&& g) = \b -> (f b, g b)`. This operator `(&&&)` is a part of the definition of the `Arrow` typeclass, so something can only be an `Arrow` from one type to another type if there is some way to perform an analogous "parallel operation" of the two arrows.

Comment: Another *great* answer. I'm going to have a hard time choosing!

Comment: The thing I was missing completely was that `a` is matching `~>` so that `a b c` matched, for example, `negate` — as `b ~> c` — which, more familiarly is also `b -> c`.

Comment: What, btw, other than a function could be an `Arrow` (in this context anyway: of being something that takes a `b` and produces a `c`)?

Comment: Every Applicative including every Monad is an arrow; see [this link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.7.0.1/docs/src/Options-Applicative-Arrows.html#A). Control.Arrow more specifically defines one for each Kleisli arrow `a -> m b` of a monad `m` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Control.Arrow.html#Kleisli). Arrows (and more confusingly, functions returning arrows) are seen a ton in the package HXT which parses XML, e.g. [the ArrowXML class](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.15/docs/Text-XML-HXT-Arrow-XmlArrow.html#t:ArrowXml).

Comment: Are there `Arrow`s other than functions that can take a `b` as an argument and return a `c`?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I mean, at the very least you have `newtype C a b = C {runC :: forall z. (b -> c -> z) -> z}` which is isomorphic to `(->)` but does not return a `c` directly. Also, the recipe for using an Applicative as an Arrow can be used with the `Applicative (Monoid m) => Const m` declaration, in which the `c` is a "phantom type variable" and the functions can never be coerced to return a `c` at all. I think the `a` must always appear as at least one argument in some function, though, and if it exists as an output this cannot affect the `(.)` function due to types.

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to skip some of the explanation of how arrows work and look at the type of `(negate &&& (+5))`:

```
> :t (negate &&& (+5))
(negate &&& (+5)) :: Num a => a -> (a, a)
```

With `negate :: a -> a` and `(+5) :: a -> a`, the function created by `&&&` takes a value of type `a` and returns a pair of values, both of which have type `a` as well.

When considering a function as an instance of `Arrow`, `b` and `c` are simply the names given to the argument and return types, respectively. That is, if `f :: b -> c` and `g :: b -> c'` are two functions that take arguments of the same type but return values of possibly different types, then `( f &&& g ) :: b -> (c, c')`, meaning the new function takes a single value of the common input type, then returns a pair consisting of the return values of each of the original functions, or `( f &&& g ) x = (f x, g x)`.