# Combine functions to a function which returns a tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tuples

Is there a function in the Haskell standard library which takes two functions and returns a function which will return the results of both these functions in a tuple, something like this:

```
(><) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
f >< g = \a -> (f a, g a)
```

So that:

```
((+2) >< (+3)) 10 == (12,13)
((:[1,2,3]) >< (*2)) 5 == ([5,1,2,3],10)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[**`&&&`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-38--38--38-) from `Control.Arrow`, has signature:

```
(&&&) :: Control.Arrow.Arrow a => a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c, c')
```

which is more generic than what you describe, but as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32550390/625914), when applied to functions, it resolves to:

```
(b -> c) -> (b -> c') -> (b -> (c, c'))
```

and it does what you describe:

```
\> import Control.Arrow ((&&&))

\> (+2) &&& (+3) $ 10
(12,13)

\> (:[1,2,3]) &&& (*2) $ 5 
([5,1,2,3],10)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Applicative` instance for functions:

```
ghci> :t liftA2 (,)
liftA2 (,) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

To make the signature more concrete, we specialize `f` to a function using `TypeApplications` (GHC >= 8):

```
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications
ghci> :t liftA2 @((->) _) (,)
liftA2 @((->)_) (,) :: (t -> a) -> (t -> b) -> t -> (a, b)
```

Comment: And, with idiom brackets, we can just write `(|f, g|)`.